# DMS - Show column Value only if another field equal specific Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm trying to update my DMS script (JSON) with the role:
if column 'type' in table X =1 then show column 'name' in table Y value,
Else, show column 'name' in table Y as null;

Example:
Table X:

| x_id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |

Table Y:

| y_id | name | x_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yossi | 2 |
| 2 | Dan | 1 |

Result for table Y after DMS process:

| y_id | name | x_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yossi | 2 |
| 2 | null | 1 |

Im using DMS to transform data from MySQL to Redshift.
Thanks